# Is it possible to make a file association with a customtool in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, customtool

I've created a customtool for VisualStudio.
Now I was wondering if it was possible to make a file association so when I create certain type of file (*.popo), it would automatically set the property field for the customtool?

Example: When you create a resx, the 'GlobalResourceProxyGenerator' is autonatically set for it. and then generate the file.

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14676106/736079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a custom file template in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If needed you can implement the [IWizard interface to set additional properties that are not supported by the template file format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14676106/736079). Setting the customtool is something that can easily be done using the IWizard interface, see the related question for a code sample.

That way you can have your `.popo` file in the Add New Item window of Visual Studio and have it set all the properties you want when creating a new file.